# Add WordPress posts in Python

Tags: python, wordpress

I want to post articles to WordPress. I try this:

```
from wordpress import API
import json

wpapi = API(
    url="http://my_domain",
    consumer_key="xxx",
    consumer_secret="xxx",
    api="wp-json",
    version="wp/v2",
    wp_user="admin",
    wp_pass="adminpass"
)

data = {
        "content": "This is the big mess I've made in python",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Stuff from python",
        "slug": "here-is-another-api-post",
        "author": "1"
        }
wpapi.post('posts', data)
```

An error says:

```
UserWarning: <exception str() failed>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Reminder: there are several helpful answers you seem not to have replied to, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48110581) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47837464).

Comment: @halfer considered!

Comment: Thank you, Ehsan.